# django form how to render the fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to render a form but the fields are not displayed in the HTML.

views.py

```
#url(r'^boxes/(?P<pk>[0-9A-Za-z-]+)/$', views.show_form, name='box'),
def show_form(request, pk):
    box = Box.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = SuggestionForm()
    context = {
    'box':box,
    'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'boxes/detail.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class SuggestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Suggestion
        fields = ['comment']
```

detail.html

```
        <h3>{{box.title}}</h3>

<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Add suggies" />
</form>
```

My models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Suggestion(models.Model):
    """
    For adding comments (or suggestions)
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment[0:10]

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)     
    comment = models.CharField("",max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    box = models.ForeignKey(Participant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

The result HTML.. There is no fields in this form. I want to use a function based view.
[image]

Comment: `form = SugboxForm()` but the form name is `SuggestionForm` ? Shouldn't this be `form = SuggestionForm()`

Comment: thanks @MevinBabu ! I corrected my Questions. But unfortunately  it's still doesn't output the fields

Comment: Does it work when you just do `{{ form }}` in the template ?

Comment: No it doesn't work either it only output this. `<applications.boxes.views.SuggestionForm object at 0xb5405cec>`

Comment: This is weird. Did you try restarting your Django development server ?

Comment: Yes did it already. But it still the same result. But when I'm using a class based view(FormView) it works. I don't know why..